# applying increasing and decreasing functions on inequality

Tags: inequality

Say $ f(x)<y $ where f is an increasing or non-decreasing function if we take the inverse on both sides do we need to flip the inequality. If f is increasing or non-decreasing, does that mean that it's inverse is decreasing or non-increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>b$ and let $f$ be an increasing function.

Let $f^{-1}(a)=p$ and $f^{-1}(b)=q$.

Hence, $a=f(p)$ and $b=f(q)$, which says that $p>q$.

Indeed, let $p\leq q$.

Since $f$ is an increasing function, we get $f(p)\leq f(q)$ or $a\leq b$, which is contradiction.

Thus, $f^{-1}(a)>f^{-1}(b)$ and $f^{-1}$ is an increasing function.

By the way, if $f$ is non-decreasing function then the inverse function to $f$ not necessarily exists.

For example: $f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be an increasing function so that $f(a)<f(b)$ for $a<b$.

The inverse function has a property: $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$.

Then: $a=f(f^{-1}(a))<f(f^{-1}(b))=b \Rightarrow f^{-1}(a)<f^{-1}(b)$, which implies $f^{-1}(x)$ is also an increasing function.